# create calculated value based on Aggregate and CASE functions

Tags: sql-server

I am working through the below query and would like to use it as a data source in Tableau - a field I will need is 'SUM_ORDERS'/'SUM_FCST' - is there anyway to calculate that in the below query given the aggregate and Case functions? Don't seem to be able to divide on the whole aggregate or on the name of the new field (ie 'SUM_FCST')  Thanks in advance.

```
SELECT  M.MATERIAL, 
        M.MATERIAL_DESCRIPTION,
        M.MATERIAL_AVAILABILITY_DATE,
        SUM(CASE WHEN M.REQUIREMENT_TYPE = 'PB' THEN M.QUANTITY ELSE 0 END) AS 'SUM_FCST',
        SUM(CASE WHEN M.REQUIREMENT_TYPE IN('01','04','KE') THEN M.QUANTITY ELSE 0 END) AS 'SUM_ORDERS',
        A.Product_Division, 
        A.BU_Group, 
        A.Business_Segment,
        A.Gender


FROM   VW_MRP_ALLOCATION M 
LEFT OUTER JOIN   vw_Article_Attributes A ON M.MATERIAL = A.Article

WHERE  M.REQUIREMENT_CATEGORY IN ('A60381000', 'A60382000')
AND    M.MATERIAL_AVAILABILITY_DATE BETWEEN GETDATE() AND GETDATE() + 90
AND    M.MATERIAL IN ('AA2721',
'AA2723',
'AA5205',
'AA5206',
'AA5207',
'AA5208',
'AA5209',
'AA5210',
'AB3120',
'AB3121',
'AB3131',
'AC5234',
'AC5235',
'AC5236',
'AC5237',
'AC5254',
'AC5256',
'AH9802',
'AH9803',
'AH9804',
'AI3331',
'AI6206',
'AJ5837',
'AJ5838',
'AJ5839',
'AJ5840',
'AJ5841',
'AJ5842',
'AJ5844',
'AJ5846',
'AJ5863',
'AJ5867',
'AJ5869',
'AJ5871',
'AJ5879',
'AJ5880',
'AJ5881',
'AJ5882',
'AJ5883',
'AJ5892',
'AJ5893',
'AJ5894',
'AJ5895',
'AJ5898',
'AJ5899',
'AJ5900',
'AJ5901',
'AJ5915',
'AJ5916',
'AJ5919',
'AN9829',
'AN9848',
'AN9854',
'AN9855',
'AO1612',
'AO1855',
'AP0354',
'AP0356',
'AP0364',
'AP0365',
'AP0366',
'AP0529',
'AP0530',
'AP0531',
'AP0534',
'AP0535',
'AP0536',
'AP0537',
'AP0540',
'AP0541',
'AP0543',
'AP0544',
'AP0545',
'AP0548',
'AP0549',
'AP0551',
'AP0552',
'AP0553',
'AP0554',
'AP0558',
'AP1855',
'AP1856',
'AP1857',
'AP1858',
'AP1859',
'AP1860',
'AP1861',
'AP1862',
'AP1863',
'AP1864',
'AP1865',
'AP1866',
'AP1867',
'AP1868',
'AP1869',
'AP1870',
'AP1871',
'AP1872',
'AP1873',
'AP1874',
'AP1875',
'AP1876',
'AP1877',
'AP1878',
'AP4362',
'AP4363',
'AP4364',
'AP4365',
'AP4366',
'AP4367',
'AP4980',
'AP4981',
'AP4982',
'AP4983',
'AP5204',
'AP5205',
'AP5206',
'AP5207',
'AP5208',
'AP5209',
'AP5210',
'AP5211',
'AP5212',
'AP5648',
'AP5649',
'AP5650',
'AP5651',
'AP5652',
'AX6087',
'AX7043',
'AY1795',
'AY1796',
'AY1839',
'AY2858',
'AY2859',
'AY2867',
'AY2868',
'AY2879',
'AY2881',
'AY2883',
'AY2885',
'AY2886',
'AY2888',
'AY2889',
'AY2890',
'AY2896',
'AY2898',
'AY2983',
'AY2984',
'AZ5389',
'AZ5390',
'AZ5395',
'AZ5396',
'AZ5398',
'AZ5400',
'AZ5402',
'AZ5406',
'B43242',
'B43243',
'B43244',
'B43245',
'B43246',
'B45108',
'B45109',
'B45110',
'B45112',
'B45113',
'BJ9093',
'BJ9095',
'BJ9096',
'BJ9097',
'BJ9098',
'BJ9103',
'BJ9110',
'BJ9111',
'BJ9112',
'BJ9113',
'BJ9114',
'BJ9121',
'BJ9126',
'BJ9127',
'BJ9128',
'BJ9129',
'BJ9131',
'BJ9137',
'BJ9143',
'BJ9144',
'BJ9145',
'BJ9147',
'BJ9148',
'BJ9152',
'BJ9161',
'BJ9163',
'BJ9164',
'BJ9165',
'BJ9166',
'BJ9171',
'BJ9173',
'BJ9174',
'BJ9176',
'BJ9177',
'BJ9179',
'BJ9185',
'BJ9186',
'BJ9189',
'BJ9192',
'BJ9194',
'BJ9195',
'BJ9196',
'BJ9197',
'BJ9198',
'BJ9200',
'BJ9201',
'BJ9202',
'BJ9203',
'BJ9205',
'BJ9206',
'BJ9207',
'BJ9226',
'BJ9228',
'BJ9229',
'BJ9231',
'BJ9294',
'BJ9296',
'BK0292',
'BK0293',
'BK0348',
'BK0350',
'BK0351',
'BK0387',
'BK4765',
'BK4766',
'BK4771',
'BK4772',
'BK4773',
'BK4774',
'BK4775',
'BK4776',
'BK4777',
'BK4778',
'BK4779',
'BK4780',
'BK4781',
'BK4782',
'BK5154',
'BK5428',
'BK5434',
'BK5435',
'BK5437',
'BK5438',
'BK5439',
'BK5444',
'BP5424',
'BP6019',
'BP6022',
'BQ2622',
'BQ2626',
'BQ2628',
'BQ2631',
'BQ2633',
'BQ2634',
'BQ2718',
'BQ2719',
'BQ2722',
'BQ2724',
'BQ2729',
'BQ2730',
'BQ2741',
'BQ2748',
'BQ2749',
'BQ2751',
'BQ2763',
'BQ2765',
'BQ2768',
'BQ2801',
'BQ2806',
'BQ2810',
'BQ2814',
'BQ2815',
'BQ6500',
'BQ7077',
'BQ8196',
'BQ8199',
'BQ8201',
'BQ8243',
'BQ8245',
'BQ8248',
'BR1977',
'BR2701',
'BR2704',
'BR2707',
'BS0042',
'BS0047',
'BS4211',
'BS4212',
'BS4213',
'BS4215',
'BS4216',
'BS4217',
'BS4219',
'BS4224',
'BS4225',
'BS4227',
'BS4228',
'BS4229',
'BS4231',
'BS4232',
'BS4235',
'BS4236',
'BS4237',
'BS4239',
'BS4240',
'BS4241',
'BS4242',
'BS4250',
'BS4252',
'BS4253',
'BS4254',
'BS4256',
'BS4257',
'BS4258',
'BS4260',
'BS4261',
'BS4262',
'BS4264',
'BS4265',
'BS4266',
'BS4268',
'BS4269',
'BS4270',
'BS4271',
'BS4273',
'BS4274',
'BS4275',
'BS4277',
'D84856',
'F82133',
'F82134',
'F82135',
'M35339',
'M35340',
'M35341',
'M64058',
'M64059',
'M64060',
'S04518',
'S05722',
'S05723',
'S05724',
'S05725',
'S05726',
'S05727',
'S05728',
'S05730',
'S05731',
'S05732',
'S05733',
'S05747',
'S05748',
'S05749',
'S05750',
'S05751',
'S05752',
'S05753',
'S05755',
'S05756',
'S05757',
'S05758',
'S16146',
'S16147',
'S16148',
'S16149',
'S16150',
'S16151',
'S16152',
'S16153',
'S16154',
'S16155',
'S16158',
'S16159',
'S16160',
'S16161',
'S16163',
'S16164',
'S17209',
'S17210',
'S17211',
'S17212',
'S17298',
'S17299',
'S17300',
'S17301',
'S17302',
'S17303',
'S17304',
'S17305',
'S17306',
'S17307',
'S17308',
'S17309',
'S17310',
'S17311',
'S17313',
'S17314',
'S22316',
'S22317',
'S22318',
'S22325',
'S22326',
'S22327',
'S22328',
'S22329',
'S22330',
'S22334',
'S22336',
'S22352',
'S22353',
'S22354',
'S22355',
'S22357',
'S22362',
'S22363',
'S22364',
'S22365',
'S22367',
'S22374',
'S22375',
'S22376',
'S22377',
'S22378',
'S22410',
'S22411',
'S22412',
'S22413',
'S22414',
'S29426',
'S29427',
'S29428',
'S29429',
'S29430',
'S86552',
'S86553',
'S86554',
'S86555',
'S86556',
'S86557',
'S86558',
'S86560',
'S86561',
'S86562',
'S86563',
'S86564',
'S86565',
'S86566',
'S86567',
'S86568',
'S86569',
'S86570',
'S86572',
'S86573',
'S86574',
'S86575',
'S92430',
'S92431',
'S92432',
'S92433',
'S92434',
'S92435',
'S92436',
'S92438',
'S92439',
'S92440',
'S92441',
'S92445',
'S92446',
'S92447',
'S92448',
'S92449',
'S92450',
'S92451',
'S92453',
'S92454',
'S92455',
'S92456',
'S93552',
'S93557',
'S96976',
'S96978',
'S99143',
'S99144',
'S99145',
'S99146',
'S99147',
'S99148',
'S99149',
'S99150',
'S99151',
'S99152',
'S99153',
'S99154',
'S99155',
'Z11471',
'Z11474',
'Z11475',
'CD8414',
'CF1045',
'CF1042',
'CF1046',
'CE9563',
'CE9755',
'CD8374',
'CF1047',
'CD8382',
'CF1039',
'CF1049',
'CE9564',
'CD8358',
'CF1044',
'CD8430',
'CE9758',
'CF1036',
'CF1043',
'CF1041',
'CF1038',
'CE9756',
'CF1050',
'CE9759',
'CD8390',
'CD8438',
'CF1037',
'CF1035',
'CD8366',
'CE9565',
'CD8398',
'Z87549')

GROUP BY M.MATERIAL, 
         M.MATERIAL_DESCRIPTION,
         M.MATERIAL_AVAILABILITY_DATE,
         A.BU_Group, 
         A.Business_Segment,
         A.Gender,
         A.Product_Division



ORDER BY M.MATERIAL,
         M.MATERIAL_AVAILABILITY_DATE
```

Comment: Why can't you just divide on the whole aggregate or using the alias of the sum'd fields. Have you tried? `SUM(CASE WHEN M.REQUIREMENT_TYPE IN('01','04','KE') THEN M.QUANTITY ELSE 0 END)/SUM(CASE WHEN M.REQUIREMENT_TYPE = 'PB' THEN M.QUANTITY ELSE 0 END) as mynewfieldfortableau`

Comment: thanks for checking it out - I did try that but get the 'divide by zero error' - the thing is I need that calculation to just return zero - trying to figure out a way to add a case when to catch that

Answer (score 2):

You could use `NULLIF` to avoid 'divide by zero error'

```
ISNULL(CAST(SUM(CASE WHEN M.REQUIREMENT_TYPE = 'PB' 
       THEN M.QUANTITY 
       ELSE 0 
    END) as decimal)
/ NULLIF(SUM(CASE 
                 WHEN M.REQUIREMENT_TYPE IN('01','04','KE') THEN M.QUANTITY 
                 ELSE 0 
             END) 
       ,0), 0) AS [SUM_ORDERS/SUM_FCST]
```

The return result is `NULL` when 'SUM_FCST' = 0

Comment: that works for situations where FCST is higher than SUM_ORDERS/SUM_FCST - but i still get 0 when there is a value in the latter column - is there a way to get a negative or show that there was more in the latter column than in the compared column?

Comment: a picture if it helps I think I know what I am missing but not sure - I need a calculation - even if it 0/0 I just need that to be 0 - when I check AC5234 it has a quantity on  month 7 for the amount of 255 in the SUM_FCST column but 0 in the SUM_ORDERS column - a bit confused on how to get that one to work

Comment: Just cast SUM_ORDERS  to decimal and use ISNULL.

Comment: the first result is the correct calculation -  I need it reversed though - i.e. 01,04.ke/pb - but when I do it i get an error on the keyword AS

Comment: NULLIF(SUM(CASE 
                 WHEN M.REQUIREMENT_TYPE IN('01','04','KE') THEN M.QUANTITY 
                 ELSE 0 
             END) 
       ,0) /SUM(CASE WHEN M.REQUIREMENT_TYPE = 'PB' 
       THEN M.QUANTITY 
       ELSE 0 END) AS [SUM_ORDERS/SUM_FCST], ---NEED TO REVERSE CALCULATION

Comment: sorry it limited the characthers

Comment: You could change to SUM(CASE WHEN M.REQUIREMENT_TYPE IN ('01','04','KE') THEN M.QUANTITY ELSE 0 END) /
NULLIF(SUM(CASE WHEN M.REQUIREMENT_TYPE = 'PB' THEN M.QUANTITY ELSE 0 END),0) AS [SUM_ORDERS/SUM_FCST]

Comment: thank you - I think this might be it - question if you are able - will it provide a percentage over 100% using that?  There are cases where that will be the case but I don't see it happening - will recheck the data though

Comment: great tip by the way

Comment: just want to make sure that the calculation can show over 100 percent - it will happen at a some point - thanks again!